# Background job while launching a Windows GUI application

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

When my Win32 application starts, `LoadDB()` should be executed and it takes at least 10 or 20 seconds. Where to execute `LoadDB()`, as a background loading task, **in order to prevent the GUI window to be non-responding?**

Is it possible to do it, but without having to create a separate `thread`? (this looked complicated and I wanted to avoid that).

---

Note: If I do it in the main message loop:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            LoadDB();
            ...
```

the GUI will be non-responding.

Comment: "this looked complicated" - doing complicated things is complicated.

Comment: Spawn a thread and put your routines there.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm ok to do it *if needed*, but I wanted to say "Isn't there another method?".

Comment: Dealing with threads in modern C++ is actually quite easy, but it looks like you are writing a C program  that you just happen to be compiling with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Then I'm okay to use this @NeilButterworth. From where would you start this action / thread? WM_CREATE / elsewhere?

Comment: I wouldn't write a Windows application using the Win32 C API. I would write it using a framework such as Qt, or a completely different language, such as C#.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ok. This would be out of topic then, because it's a standard WinAPI app, without any Qt or .net or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a thread really isn't nearly as complex as it may initially seem.

When you need to support interaction between threads, things can be fairly complex--but in this case, all you need is to start something, and later get a notification that it's done. That's it.

So, what you want to do is write a small function that calls loadDB(), then (for example) calls `PostMessage` to let the rest of your application know that the DB is loaded and ready to use.

There's really not much more to it than that. Seriously, it's really not complex or complicated.

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin. Will the `std::vector<std:wstring>` loaded by Thread2 during `LoadDB()` be accessible by MainThread once the loading is done?

Comment: @Basj: If you want it accessible, you'll need to make sure it's accessible. If (for example) it's a global variable, then yes that'll be accessible. If it's dynamically allocated, you'll need to pass its address back to the rest of the code to let them know where it lives. But ultimately, threads all share the same address space, so what you do in one thread you can make visible to the others pretty easily.